# Calculating package number from single line which consist of integers

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I am trying to read in a list of numbers as a string and calculate how many packages there should be. Each package has a maximum of 50. For example, the output of `"25 25 25 -1"` should be 2 but I am getting 1.

Could you please review my code?

```
int main(void) {
  int input = 0;
  int diff = 50;
  int output = 0;

  printf("Input: \n");
  do {
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if (input < diff) {
      diff -= input;

    } else if (diff == input) {
      diff = 50;
      output++;
    } else {
      diff = 50 - input;
      output++;
    }

  } while (input != -1);

  printf("Output: %d", output);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You read input at the start of the loop and compare it to -1 at the end of the loop, so -1 will get processed the same as every other input

Comment: @jsonkiller You not considering the package boundaries. If your input is "26 26 26 -1" Then you would need 3 package since a package can only hold 50 so after putting in 26 there is no place for the next one. Your (fixed) algorithm would still say 2.

Comment: With the applied changed mentioned in the answer? For what input?

Comment: don't remove code like that, which invalidates your question and its answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you read into `input` once at the *start* of the loop and compare it to `-1` at the *end* of the loop, so `-1` will get processed the same as every other `input` value.

The obvious option is to read in two different places, once before the loop, and once at the end of the loop, this way you'll get a new `input` value *directly before* your loop condition:

```
printf("Input: \n");
scanf("%d", &input);
while(input != -1) {
    // Processing
    scanf("%d", &input);
}
```

Note that I've also switched the loop to a `while` loop instead of a `do ... while` loop as if the input provided *only* contains `-1` then a `do ... while` would still process it, resulting in the wrong output.

---

You also don't take into account that a package may be incomplete at the end of your loop, this can be solved by checking to see if you have an uncounted package after your loop:

```
printf("Input: \n");
scanf("%d", &input);
while(input != -1) {
    // Processing
    scanf("%d", &input);
} 
if(diff != 50) {
    output++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to use the "-1" as part of the processed data.

Also take a look at your algorithm.

Maybe something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int input = 0;
  int load = 50;
  int output = 0;

  printf("Input: \n");
  while (1) {
    if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1 || input > 50)
    {
        // Illegal input
        exit(1);
    }
    if (input == - 1)
    {
        // Done
        break;
    }

    if (load + input > 50)
    {
        ++output;  // Take new package
        load = 0;  // make it empty
    }

    load += input; // Put into package
  };

  printf("Output: %d", output);

  return 0;
}
```